# Mixing lod and non-lod calculations

Tags: tableau-api

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

I want to use a parameter to select a value from `Group` and then compute `Ratio` which is `Value` divided by `Value` when `Group == parameter`. The image above is the desired output when the parameter equals D.

I thought that this would do the trick:

```
[Value]/{EXCLUDE [GROUP]: MAX(VALUE)}
```

But I just get nulls.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOD expressions dont work that way and they will always show as null values in the datasource page. Here is the  [Documentation](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html#Limitations_for_Level_of_Detail_Expressions). (Bullet point 2)

For your case, create the parameter as shown below. (You can use 'Paste from clipboard' as by default only values can be assigned by field and not 'Display As'.)

[image]

Now your calculation simply becomes

> [Value]/[Selected_Group]

[image]

Comment: Welp that's a lot easier than the alternative method I came up with. Thanks!